# uninitialized constant Users::RegistrationsController::Shortener Devise + Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, url-shortener

I'm using a gem called Shortener: https://github.com/jpmcgrath/shortener
Its goal is to shorten some urls of my website such as `www.mywebsite.com/users/sign_up?&invitcode="test"` would become `www.mywebsite.com/shorturl`.

I meet a problem in my Devise **registration_controller.rb** where I'm trying to use this gem. When I called it with `Shortener::ShortenedUrl.generate("www.example.com")` I get a `uninitialized constant Users::RegistrationsController::Shortener`.

If I do the same command in my console, it's working perfectly. I guess it's because Rails cannot find Shortener in my devise module? Can you tell me how I should solve this?

[image]

Comment: Can you please try to use shortener in that file like this: short = Shortener.new short::ShortenedUrl.generate("http://example.com")

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nezir. Unfortunately it's giving me : `undefined method 'new' for Shortener:Module` on `short = Shortener.new `

Comment: if you try ss = Shortener::ShortenedUrl.new

Comment: It's giving me this : `undefined method 'generate' for #<Shortener::ShortenedUrl:0x00007fdbd05d5148>` If it may help, in the gem code https://github.com/jpmcgrath/shortener/blob/develop/app/models/shortener/shortened_url.rb: `class Shortener::ShortenedUrl < ActiveRecord::Base`